# Null reference exception (Downloading a BLOB file from mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Im trying to download a blob file from mysql database when a link button is clicked. Following is my code:

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
if (context.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
{
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
}

try
{
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex) {
    LinkButton2.Text = "No file was uploaded";
}
```

But it gives null reference exception on "bytes". Bytes is initialized here in following statement

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(r["proposalDoc"]))
{
    this.bytes = (byte[])r["proposalDoc"];
}
```

Code for retrieval of Data:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Time = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            String query = "Select * from event where time='" + this.Time + "'";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

            DateTime time = DateTime.Today;

            conn.Open();

            MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (r.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = r["name"].ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = r["Proposedby"].ToString();
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(r["proposalDoc"]))
                {
                    this.bytes = (byte[])r["proposalDoc"];
                }

                TextBox5.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
                TextBox6.Text = r["time"].ToString();
                TextBox7.Text = r["Society"].ToString();
                TextBox8.Text = r["venue"].ToString();

            }
```

Moreover, the record exists in the database for proposalDoc

Comment: I don't see the code to actually retrieve the record.

Comment: That works just fine. Let me post it

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on this.byte = .... to ensure that your if condition is true at least once in the read?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to get the first non-null value for proposalDoc, note that ([per the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

> DBNull.Value is used to indicate a value that is missing. It is not
>   equivalent to null or to String.Empty. Therefore, code such as
>   Convert.IsDBNull(null) in C# or Convert.IsDBNull(Nothing) in Visual
>   Basic returns false.

Therefore, if `r["proposalDoc"]` is `null`, you will be assigning `null` to `this.bytes`.

The quickest way to overcome this is to null coalesce the assignment:

```
this.bytes = this.bytes ?? (byte[])r["proposalDoc"];
```

Comment: Giving an error. The problem is that the record does exist.

Comment: If it exists for *all* rows that your query reads, put a breakpoint inside the if statement and see if this.bytes is ever being assigned.  If it is, see what the value you're assigning it is.